# How to call function in WordPress on button click?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

I am new in WordPress plugin development. how can I call to  function on button click with wordPRess shortcode?

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 *Plugin Name: Testing
 *Description:
 **/
 
 function showMessage(){
     echo '<script>alert("Welcome to custom plugin") </script>'; 
 }
  function callFun(){
      
      $button1 = "<button type='button' onclick='showMessage()'>Click to Alert</button>";
      
      return $button1;
  }
  add_shortcode('example','callFun');
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  PHP runs on the server and JS in the browser.  To bridge that gap, you will need to make an AJAX call to your function in WP.  This covers the basics on how to get started: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thank you so much @jdm2112  :-)